# How to run a command in cmd on startup in Windows XP

Tags: express, windows-xp

Sigh. For reasons, I am running a windows xp virtual box in ubuntu. In this instance of windows there is an express (node) server running. Everything works fine, except that occasionally windows crashes or the virtual box freezes (perhaps after being left idle for several days). I would like to restart the virtual box (and node server) programmatically when this happens. The actual restarting of the virtual box from linux seems attainable, but I can't figure out how to get windows to run "node .../server.js" on startup! I tried putting the command in C:\AUTOEXEC.bat, and it did not start when I restarted the computer. I know I'm asking for trouble with a 10 year old OS but it's what I have to work with. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try scheduling in as a task in the task scheduler.

Tasks get executed when their triggers are satisfied, and in this case you can use the 'at startup' trigger, as described here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841.aspx

> At startup
>
> This trigger causes the task to run when the computer starts up. The only settings for this trigger are the advanced settings described in the Advanced Settings section below.

Look out though, that information wasn't tailor-made for XP, but should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just got it working. I put a batch file in start/programs/startup that CD'd to the right directory and then ran node.